# Paypal Adaptive Payment Redirect URL GET Variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

Up to now I have been using Paypal Payments Standard, making Paypal buttons which allow my customers to pay on Paypal and then redirect them to my site. I use PDT to show receipts when they return to my site, and use IPN to actually log the transaction in my database (since they often dont wait to auto-return-- I use PDT to just show a receipt to those that do).

I would like to move away from Payments Standard and use Adaptive Payments. I made some basic calls and all seems to be OK (the payments are being processed in the sandbox correctly), but when it redirects to my site it isn't passing the return url the transaction ID like it did before with PDT. Once it redirects to my website, how am I supposed to get at the payment information? I am aware of the PaymentDetails API, but how do I get the transaction ID or pay-key?

Comment: Note: To clarify, I understand that IPN will POST to my web app like before, so I can log the payment as before. I just want to show a receipt when the user is redirected to my site, like I did before with Payments Standard and PDT. Why doesn't Adaptive Payments pass any GET variables to my return url?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can help. For every payment request, I save to database its  tracking id and pay-key. This tracking id is included in my return url body and I used it in [PaymentDetails API](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPaymentDetails) to retrieve payment information.

By the way, this tracking id is generated in my code.

Comment: Yea, thanks, I thought of this as a possibility too. Seems like doing duplicate work though to have to come up with my own tracking id, when the pay-key IS a unique way of tracking. Would be much more convenient if they could just pass the transaction id or pay-key via a get param to my return url. This is exactly how they did it with PDT, not sure why its not happening with Adaptive Payments. I'm not sure how else I could show a receipt on my return url...

Answer (score 0):

look at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro

and use an IPNListener (samples/IPN/IPNListener.php for Adaptive Payments PHP version)